# Proof of floor function identity.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and let $l$ be the greatest integer $\le x$

How do I prove $l + 1 > x$

I see that:

$x \ge \lfloor x \rfloor = l$

**No complete answers, just hints**

Comment: If $l+1>x$ isn't the case, then we must have $l+1\leqslant x$, but this contradicts the definition of $l$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows up from floor definition :

$\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the unique integer $n$ such that :
$$n\leq x<n+1$$

(if you have another definition of floor, please specify it)